# Removing or overriding Windows 7 system image in windows 8

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, windows-8.1, backup, system-restore

Before upgrading my PC to Windows 8.1, I did a standard Windows 7 backup to a 1TB hard drive. Now that I am in Windows 8.1, I would like to create a new System Image Backup, however I don't think the backup wizard has detected the previous backup to override. Is there a way to do that?

Otherwise I wouldn't mind just deleting the old system image backup from my hard drive, however I thought I should check here if that is a safe thing to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's safe to delete the old system image.